# Get the part of a line before the last slash

Tags: text-processing, grep, cut, mpd

I'm trying to write a conky script that shows my MPD album art, a 'folder.jpg' in the album folder. My current plan is to use `mpc -f %file%`, which prints out the file name and path, and then cut out the actual file name (i.e. everything after the last /), and use that as the path to for conky's image object.

I'm having trouble with grep/cut, particularly since some songs are nested in two folders, while others are in one. (`grep -m 1 . |cut -f1 -d /` works for the single folder albums)

How would I go about this? Is there a simpler way I'm missing?

Comment: Do you want the directory part up to the last `/`, or the file name without leading directory parts? “Cut out” is ambiguous, and we've interpreted it differently.

Comment: @Gilles From his example with single folder albums, the OP wants to keep the part before the last slash.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `sed` to remove the rest - *everything starting with the last slash*:

`mpc -f %file% | head -1 | sed 's:/[^/]*$::'`

The pattern `/[^/]*$` matches a slash, followed by any characters except slash, up to the end of the line. It is replaced by the empty string.
The `head -1` ignores some status output following the line we want - but see below for how to not pring them in the first place.

In case you are not used to sed, the command may look unusual because of the `:` used. You may have seen `sed` commands with `/` as separator before, like `'s/foo/bar/'` - I prefer to use the separator `:` for readability, as the expression contains `/` itself. Alternatively, we could escape the `/` in the expression: `'s/\/[^\/]*$//'` - that does not make it more readable.

---

The way you use it with `mpc` gives you two additional status lines. The option `-q` for quiet switches off all the output. You need to combine `-q` with explicitly printing the current playing file to get the line yon need, and nothing more:

`mpc -q -f %file% current | sed 's:/[^/]*$::'`

Instead of removing *everything starting with the last slash*, one could explicitly print *everything before the last slash*:

`mpc -q -f %file% current | sed 's:^\(.*\)/.*$:\1:'`

That matches any characters that are followed by a `/` and any other characters; It matches as much as possible, so that the `/` that is matched will be the last one.

Comment: Great, thanks. The -q flag helped a lot too.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to apply this rule on a single string, then instead of `sed` (see the other answer), you can use the `dirname` command:

```
$ dirname "1 2/3 4/5 6/file"
1 2/3 4/5 6
```

Answer (score 2):

Grep isn't the last tool for the job. `grep -m 1 .` prints the first non-empty line, which isn't useful. You can construct complex solutions that involve grep and other tools, but the straightforward way is with [sed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed). One way is to replace a final run of non-slash characters, plus the preceding slash, by the empty string:

```
mpc -f %file% | sed 's:/[^/]*$::'
```

Alternatively, keep everything up to the last slash and discard what follows:

```
mpc -f %file% | sed 's:^\(.*\)\(/.*\)$:\1:'
```

Beware that both methods leave the input unchanged if it doesn't contain a `/`, i.e. if you pass a file name with no directory indication. While you can solve this in sed if it's an issue, it's easier to invoke the [`dirname` command](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dirname):

```
dirname -- "$(mpc -f %file%)"
```

In a shell script, you can also use [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) constructs, but this is more complex if you just want to print out the result:

```
full_path="$(mpc -f %file%)"
case "$full_path" in
  */*) directory_part="${full_path%/*}"
  *) directory_part="."
printf '%s\n' "$directory_part"
```