# Strip the file base name, keep the directory part

Tags: text-processing, sed, regular-expression

I have a string which looks something like this

```
dir/subdir/othersubdir/file.txt
```

But it can also look like

```
dir/file.txt
```

or

```
dir/subdir/file.txt
```

Now, I am making a script where `$P` is the full path to the directory were `file.txt` is.

Now I use this

```
sed 's/\/.*txt//g'
```

To be replace anything that ends with txt and comes after a `/`. This works fine when there is something like `dir/file.txt`, but not any of my other examples. How can I fix so that it matches what I want?

I don't want to match any subdirectories before `.*txt`. I want to remove only the file base name.

Comment: Its the other way around.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the part of a line before the last slash](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153409/get-the-part-of-a-line-before-the-last-slash)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't insist on using `sed` then you could consider using `dirname`:

```
S="dir/subdir/othersubdir/file.txt"
P=$(dirname $S)
echo $P
dir/subdir/othersubdir

S="dir/file.txt"
P=$(dirname $S)
echo $P
dir
```

Comment: Lol, there is an actual dedicated command to this, thanks.

Comment: @DisplayName - yes, and if you want the opposite (just the filename without the path) you can use the `basename` command.

Answer (score 2):

Here is `sed` command:

```bsh
$ P="dir/subdir/othersubdir/file.txt"
$ sed -r 's/^(.*)\/.*\.txt$/\1/' <<< $P
dir/subdir/othersubdir
```

In above `sed` command we capture anything`.*` from beginning`^` of variable `P` that ends`$` with`/*.txt`, which it's known as a captured group with`\1` as its beck-reference because used a pair of parentheses around it`(.*)`, then in replacement part of sed command, we prints only captured group by using its back-reference.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `zsh` life is much simpler, just use `:h` modifier:

```
$ var='dir/subdir/othersubdir/file.txt'
$ echo "$var:h"
dir/subdir/othersubdir
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -ne 'put IO::Spec::Unix.splitpath($_).[1];'    file.txt
```

#OR (on Unix)

```perl
~$ raku -ne 'put .IO.dirname;'    file.txt
```

Raku is a programming language in the Perl-family. The first code example above takes your file paths and treats them as `IO` objects, of which there are four main classes (Unix, Windows, Cygwin, and QNX). Because your file consists of Unix paths, the `IO::Spec::Unix` method is called, to correctly understand the path delimiter, etc. (Note these separate functions allow you to, for example, manipulate Windows paths on a Unix box). Then `splitpath` breaks the path into three parts: Volume, Path, and File Name (index `.[1]` gives you the file name).

On Unix this code simplifies in the second example to `put .IO.dirname;`.

Sample Input:

```
dir/subdir/othersubdir/file.txt
dir/subdir/file.txt
dir/file.txt
```

Sample Output:

```
dir/subdir/othersubdir
dir/subdir
dir
```

https://docs.raku.org/type/IO/Spec/Unix
https://docs.raku.org/routine/dirname
https://raku.org